# How to compare string with enum values and return corresponding enum value in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, enums

```
    var stringValue: String = "ort"
```

How to compare `stringValue` with `nameOfCode` from `Data` enum class and get get corresponding `code` value from enum class in Kotlin in android.

```
enum class Data(val nameOfCode: String, val code: String) {
    WES("wes", "6"),
    ORT("ort", "70"),
    R("R", "7"),
    RON("Ron", "6,7"),
    LO("Lo", "6,70"),
    OT("ot", "7,70"),
    ALL("All", "6,7,7000")
}
```

Eg: Here string value is "ort" so in enum ort corresponding code value is "70". How to get this value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the corresponding entry in the enum and get its code, like this:

```kotlin
val code = Data.values().find { it.nameOfCode == nameToBeSearched }?.code
```

This will give null if `nameToBeSearched` does not match with any `nameOfCode` in the enum.